# How to run webtests from a TFS build using powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell, tfs, build, azure-devops

I have a requirement to run webtests which are located in a particular folder through a build. Currently the tests are run from Visual Studio 2015. 
Got to know to execute/use the below powershell script as a task. But clueless how to implement it. Is this powershell script enough?.

```
param 
(
$tool = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe",
$path ,
$include = "*.webtest" 
 )
$web_tests = get-ChildItem -Path $paths -Recurse -Include $include
foreach ($item in $web_tests) {
$args += "/TestContainer:$item"
}
```

In this, how to pass in the $path value? Do I need to give the path of the directory which has all these 5 webtests?
Do I need a testsettings file to carry out this execution.

If I need a test settings file, do I need to copy all the webtests file to output directory?

All I get with this powershell is the below message

```
 No test runs are available for this build. Enable automated tests in 
 your build definition by adding a task that runs tests for your test 
 framework of choice, such as the Visual Studio Test task. If you choose 
 to run tests using a custom task or runner, you can publish results 
 using the Publish Test Results task
```

Could any one please help me as in what I am missing here? Thanks for your time and help on this.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

> how to pass in the $path value?

When you use the [powershell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) to execute your powershell scripts, there is a option [Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops#arguments), which you could pass the value of `$path`:

[image]

> Do I need to give the path of the directory which has all these 5
>   webtests?

Yes. In general, the `.webtests` file are all copied to the drops location, so the path always point to the drops location.

> Do I need a testsettings file to carry out this execution.

The short answer is yes.

There is a great blog about how to [Running WebTests as part of a VSTS VNext Release pipeline](https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/rfennell/2016/05/30/running-webtests-as-part-of-a-vsts-vnext-release-pipeline/), you can check if it helps.

Hope this helps.